# Ajax-Request: Passing Dynamic Content to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I never used jquery before and tried hard to find a solution for my case.

On the cockpit.php page I use a form to get some content from a mysql database. Meanwhile I am able to show this content in a div on the cockpit.php page.

The plan is to show the content in a modal. There the user has 10 seconds to confirm it (in this case it should be stored to the database).

The problem: I tried it for hours and days to get the content into the modal. No chance... Any idea on how to solve this? Btw: At the moment I reload the window after the countdown reaches zero. Here it would also be an idea to just close to modal via jquery.

So I would really appreciate some hints. Thx.

**Final Solution:**
modal.js

```
$(function(){

  $("#pricing").submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {                 
             $('#myModal').find('#a').text(data.a);
             $('#myModal').find('#b').text(data.b);     
             $('#myModal').find('#c').text(data.c);
             $('#myModal').find('#d').text(data.d);
             $('#myModal').find('#e').text(data.e);
             $('#myModal').find('#f').text(data.f);
             $('#a2').val($(this).data('a'));
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
             }
           });
      return false;  
  });

});


   $("#confirm").click(function(){
    var data = {
    a: $('#a').text(),
    b: $('#b').text(),
    c: $('#c').text()
};    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'confirm.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(confirm)  {                 
             window.location.reload();

             }
    });
});
```

relevant HTML-part of the Modal for click-function:

```
 <div class="alert hidden" role="alert" id="modalAlert"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="confirmmodal" name="confirmmodal" value="" /> 
                    </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-ar btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-ar btn-primary" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
          </div>
```

confirm.php

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    // do what you want
    $confirm = array('message' => $a);
    echo json_encode($confirm);
```

So the functionality works fine...

Comment: Can you tell me when you have the issue passing the data to the modal? Is the issue when you wanna display the data from the html when you show the modal, or is it when the response is back from the server and you wanna show the response?

Comment: I can pass the data (response from the server) and can show it in a div... this works fine. But when I try to get this data in to modal, I do not get the response. At least I cannot see it in the modal - I am of course able to see the modal (without response). A few attempts were interrupted by the reloading of the page (so the modal does not even open)

Comment: Ok, as I understand the server response should be already there as expected. I noticed a small potential issue in your code, try to add .show at the end of the line in AJAX, like this: $('#pricing').find('.form_result').html(response).show

Comment: Still the same... I guess I have to find a solution to call the modal properly and simultaneously get the data via ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a full example for you, I use it on my website. This is a html file with a link and a modal, the required JQuery and a simple php code to simulate the server response. It shows you, how you can pass data to the modal, how to show the modal and display the server response.

Just copy the files into the same directory and test it, it works for me.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog ">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert hidden" role="alert" id="modalAlert"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="myModalID" name="myModalID" value="" />
                <p>Modal example.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="myModalButton">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <a class="openModalLink" href="/" data-id="1234" data-name="Stackoverflow answer">
                  <span> Click me to open modal</span>
                </a>
            </div>          
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(function(){

  $(".openModalLink").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();       
      $("#myModalTitle").html('Hello, my name is '+$(this).data('name')+'!');
      $("#myModalID").val($(this).data('id'));

      $('#myModal').modal('show');

  });

  $("#myModalButton").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
             url: '/function.php',
             data: {
               id: $("#myModalID").val()
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {                 

              $('#myModal').find('#modalAlert').addClass('alert-success');
              $('#myModal').find('#modalAlert').html(data.message).show; 
              $('#myModal').find('#modalAlert').removeClass('hidden');

             }
       });    
  });

});
```

function.php

```
<?php

    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'You submitted this id: ' . $_GET['id']));
```

hope this helps, feel free to ask me

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENT**

I created another version that will take data from the form on the html page, pass it to php and then display the results from php on the modal window. It uses a different javascript, because now we are "post"-ing the form data to php. Here are the files:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog ">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert hidden" role="alert" id="modalAlert"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="myModalID" name="myModalID" value="" />
                <p>Modal example.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="myModalButton">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
               <form class="form-inline" id="myForm" action="/function.php" method="post">
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="myInput">Input data</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" name="myInput" placeholder="Enter data here">
                 </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
               </form>
              </div>
            </div>          
            </div>          
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(function(){

  $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {

      $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {                 

                //display data...
                $('#myModal').find('#modalAlert').addClass('alert-success');
                $('#myModal').find('#modalAlert').html(data.message).show; 
                $('#myModal').find('#modalAlert').removeClass('hidden');

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
             }
           });

      return false;  
  });

});
```

function.php

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array('message' => 'You submitted this data: ' . $_POST['myInput']));
```

Comment: great, this was definitaley a big step in the right direction. the second part of the javascript is perfect for the purpose.

Comment: Just one question: I would like to get the form data (i.E. form from index html), pass them to php and open the result in the modal. The second step is then to confirm this data (it is an offer) and save it to the db. The second step will work with your script. But to get the data into the form is still a issue.

Comment: Your script works well but it does not solve the issue to get the data. I tried  'var myform = document.getElementById("formid");
    var fd = new FormData(myform );' and then the $.ajax. How can I call  and show the vars in the success: ?

Comment: I added a modified solution to the original answer, please have a look, it does what you described in your previous comment

Comment: @mgw was my answer helpful? I put the working code up there, so I am curious wether we achieved something together :)

Comment: Your examples were really great. I updated the script in the initial question. At the moment I just have one minor problem to solve: The  $("#confirm").click(function() does not work anymore. I try to get the data from the modal (which are successfully calculated from a form and successfully shown when the modal opens:  $("#pricing").submit(function() {.

I still try to solve this... but we already achieved a lot, thx